# twine fails to check SSL certificate

Tags: gitlab-ci, pypi, python-poetry, twine

I am trying to upload Python package to private gitlab package registry using CI.

```yaml
  script:
    - poetry build
    - pip install twine
    - echo "[distutils]" > ~/.pypirc
    - echo "index-servers = gitlab" >> ~/.pypirc
    - echo "[gitlab]" >> ~/.pypirc
    - echo "repository=$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/pypi" >> ~/.pypirc
    - echo "username=gitlab-ci-token" >> ~/.pypirc
    - echo "password=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" >> ~/.pypirc
    - twine upload --repository gitlab dist/* --verbose --cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
```

When running `curl --verbose https://****repository url****` within the same CI job it shows that `SSL certificate verify ok.`.

But CI job fails, showing:

```
$ twine upload --repository gitlab dist/* --verbose --cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
INFO     Using configuration from /root/.pypirc                                 
INFO     ca_cert set by command options                                         
Uploading distributions to 
https://***********.com/api/v4/projects/53/packages/pypi
INFO     dist/************.whl (30.0 KB)                
INFO     dist/************.tar.gz (25.1 KB)                          
INFO     username set from config file                                          
INFO     password set from config file                                          
INFO     username: gitlab-ci-token                                              
INFO     password: <hidden>                                                     
Uploading ************.whl
WARNING  Retrying (Retry(total=9, connect=5, read=None, redirect=None,          
         status=None)) after connection broken by                               
         'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
         certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Please suggest what can be wrong or what can I try to do as well?

p.s. I have also tried using Poetry directly:

```
    - poetry build
    - poetry config repositories.gitlab "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi"
    - poetry config certificates.gitlab.cert "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt"
    - poetry config http-basic.gitlab gitlab-ci-token "$CI_JOB_TOKEN"
    - poetry config --list
    - poetry publish --repository gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN
```

But it gives error that server is unreachable and I should check url.

Comment: Does your GitLab server have a certificate that is issued by a well-known Certificate Authority? Or is it some kind of self-signed certificate or certificate issued by an internal CA?

Comment: @sytech, i believe its self signed

Comment: @sytech, actually I may be wrong. I see that self signed certificates are causing twine throw ssl error stating that the certificate is self signed, while my error indicates that it is unable to get the local issuer of the certificate... I am not sure what should be done in this case